# Custom file upload button

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload

spent hours on end searching the net but it seems im looking for one thing and finding another, either that or what i want just cannot be done. i do not want to re-style the `<input type="file">` i want to create a custom button that brings up a browse window, lets the user select a file of certain types, populates a seperate text box with the file name and stores the rest of the information in a way that could be passed to a php upload script after the user has filled in the rest of the form.  So in other words i want to re-invent the `<input type="file">`.

Comment: Are you prepared to use Flash?

Comment: It cannot be done like that.. You would need to investigate a flash based uploading system if you wanted to change the current method.

Comment: if that is the only solution, i want to create a foolproof site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Uploadify is a powerful and highly-customizable file upload script.  In its simplest form, Uploadify is easy to get up and running with minimal effort and little coding knowledge.

Uploadify can also be modified to suits the needs of more advanced developers via the arsenal of custom options that are available.

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

buttonImg parameter : we can give the image/text which we wanted to show ie we can customize browse button.

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done in regular html, but possible to do using flash or silverlight etc. You might want to have a look at [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php), which is a fairly foolproof upload solution in my opinion.

Comment: after searching for flash based systems i also found uploadify which looking at it fits my needs a little bit better. will comment again bit later when i have tried and tested. thanks for the suggestions and help

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, the browse button is implemented in a very secure way, not allowing it to be styled or to do any tricks with it. This is because it could in some way allow the developer to trick the user in uploading a different file then intended.

Answer (score 0):

in simple php its possible.
try this
+Create Album